# Play Model save function isn't actually writing to the database

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have a play model called "JobStatus" and it's just got one property, an enum with a JobState, (Running/notRunning).

The class extends model and is implemented as a singleton. You call it's getInstance() method to get the only record in the underlying table.

I have a job that runs every month and in the job I will toggle the state of the JobStatus object back and forth at various times and call .save().

I've noticed it isn't actually saving.

When the job starts off, it's first line of code is

```
JobStatus thisJobStatus = jobStatus.getInstance();
...// exit if already running

thisJobStatus.JobState = JobState.Running;
thisJobStatus.save()
```

then when the job is done it will change the status back to NotRunning and save again.

The issue is that when I look in the MySql database the actual record value is never changed.

This causes a catastrophic failure because when other nodes try to run the job they check the state and since they're seeing it as NotRunning, they all try to run the job also.

So my clever scheme for managing job state is failing because the actual value isn't getting commited to the DB.

How do I force Play to write to the DB right away when I call .save() on a model?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: BTW I tried declaring the function as non transactional per Play's docs but that didn't work.

Comment: ...if it's because of transactions ...

Comment: I'm only thinking it might be because toggling the job state and writing it to the DB is an operation that happens within a long running Play Job.

Comment: I tried using .flush() and that doesn't commit it to the DB. If I use flush and commit it does write to the DB, but then all the other statements surrounding it throw an exception stating no transaction is available.

Comment: Play has to support writing objects to the DB in an ad-hoc manner, this is really frustrating.

Comment: So the entire job runs under one transaction? I want to be able to commit the save to my job's state as it progresses without necessarily committing the rest of the job's work until the job is finished. How do I have a long running job and weaved into it save objects to disk right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this to your JobStatus and call it after save.

```
public static void commit(){
    JobStatus.em().getTransaction().commit();
    JobStatus.em().getTransaction().begin();
    JobStatus.em().flush();
    JobStatus.em().clear();
}
```

Comment: this partially worked, the state was set to "Running" and then the job ran, but at the end of the job when i went to change the state back to "NotRunning", and then I called .save() and then .commit(), on my existing instance of JobStatus, I get the following error. `PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.JobStatus`. Is my instance no longer valid for saving after the initial save? Do I need to call getInstance() again to re-query it from the DB?

Comment: I am so smart SMRT. I had to re-populate the object from the DB. so now I have a helper function. `// Helpers for managing job state
 private void MarkJobRunning() {
  BillingJob thisJob = BillingJob.getInstance();
  thisJob.state = JobState.Running;
  thisJob.save();
  thisJob.commit();
 }
 
 private void MarkJobNotRunning() {
  BillingJob thisJob = BillingJob.getInstance();
  thisJob.state = JobState.NotRunning;
  thisJob.save();
  thisJob.commit();
 }`  Thank you so much @emt14 !! Is this a good practice in general though? I'm tempted now to add a commit method to all my models.

Comment: I am not sure if it is good or bad practice. However your job will run in a transaction so it is the only way to get your data persisted to the db whilst the job is still running. Well actually there is another one. It is possible to call another job from your initial job. The second job will start a separate transaction and the data modified in that job will be persisted whilst the first one still runs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to mark your job as "running" pretty much as the first thing when the job starts? In that case, you shouldn't have any other ongoing database statements yet...

To commit your changes in the database immediately (instead of after the job has ended), add the following commands after the `thisJobStatus.save();` method call:

```
JPA.em().flush();
JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
```

Additionally, since you're using MySQL, you might want to lock the row immediately upon retriveval using the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` clause. (See [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for more information.) Of course, you wouldn't want to have that in your `getInstance()` method, otherwise every fetch operation would lock the record.

Comment: I tried this a bunch yesterday Tom but it always caused errors when the DB statements of the job when the commence. @emt14 's solution worked. by putting the transaction commit into a function within the actual model itself the commit doesn't seem to break the rest of the job.